# how do I write to stdout from an MFC program?

Tags: c++, mfc, stdout

MFC programs can't normally write to stdout. MFC does something weird with the stdout/stdin pipes during startup and anything you write (for example doing a printf("hello");) just goes to /dev/null.

Does anyone know how to successfully write to stdout from an MFC program?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [AllocConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681944(v=vs.85).aspx) function to create a console for writing into. The following article explains how to use it to print to console.

[Creating a console for your MFC app's debug output](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/debug/mfcconsole.aspx)

Dont forget to [FreeConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683150(v=vs.85).aspx) once you're done with it.

Comment: This is almost what I want, but you are creating a new console. I was using AttachToConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS) and getting nothing. But the solution is _cprintf() which you have given me. Hence you get the points. Thanks!

Comment: @Stephen: Probably you also want to see [AttachConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681952(v=vs.85).aspx) function. It's a bit different than what you were experimenting with.

Comment: This creates a new console window when I call my EXE from a command line. How to write the output to same console window?

Answer (score 15):

After spending an entire day trying to make my MFC program to print using printf() and cout I finally found a solution and decide to post it here to help who wants to print at MFC...

```
void EnablePrintfAtMFC()
{
    if (AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS))
    {
        FILE* pCout;
        freopen_s(&pCout, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
        std::cout.clear();
        std::wcout.clear();
    }
}
```

Just call the above function in some place of your program, and after that you will be able to use printf() and cout...

```
EnablePrintfAtMFC();
printf("Hello world!\n");
std::cout << "It works!" << endl;
```

Comment: This was the only one that worked for me out of all of the above answers - so thanks for posting it! :)

Comment: This works even on Windows 10! And it works for any GUI Windows application so you can rename it to "EnablePrintfAtGUI" :)

Answer (score 14):

If you are just looking for output to the debug window, you can use TRACE.

```
TRACE("This is a debug string of text in MFC");
```

I do this when I am quickly testing something and don't want to use dialog boxes, like MessageBox("text").

Comment: This is not answering the question I asked.

Answer (score 10):

This will attach to the calling console window, if one is present. `GotConsoleAttach` will be `FALSE` when the application wasn't called from a console.

```
GotConsoleAttach = FALSE;    
if (AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS))
{   
    int osfh = _open_osfhandle((intptr_t) GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 8);
    if ((HANDLE)osfh != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        *stdout = *_tfdopen(osfh, _T("a"));
        GotConsoleAttach = TRUE;
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked great for me. On a side note, since this is a windows app, I had used `START /WAIT myapp.exe` in order for it to work correctly.

Comment: This crashes on Windows 10.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a one-liner that I found online a while back that attaches stdout to a console in MFC. This allows printf and cout to write to the console window of the current process. I never looked into how it works, so if you need a cerr or cin version you're on your own.

```
AllocConsole();
*stdout = *_tfdopen(_open_osfhandle((intptr_t) GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), _O_APPEND), _T("a"));
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. I needed to include <fcntl.h>.

Comment: This crashes on Windows 10.