# How do we write some statement to the console screen from an MFC application?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I has a `mfc` application which I am launching through command prompt. Where I will enter some specified syntax.
If I had given wrong syntax, as of now I am showing a message box. But instead of showing message can I write the same message to the same console where I am trying
to launch my application?

Can anyone kindly let me know how we can write to the console from an MFC application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do I write to stdout from an MFC program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094502/how-do-i-write-to-stdout-from-an-mfc-program)

Answer (score 1):

I think 
[Console::WriteLine()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/zdf6yhx5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [AttachConsole()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681952%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can do the trick

example:

```
#include "windows.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "kernel32.lib")

[STAThread]
int main()
{
    AttachConsole(-1);  //Use the console of the parent of the current process.

    Console::WriteLine("wrongsyntax");  //This will write to the command prompt

    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false); 
    Application::Run(gcnew Project::MyForm);
}
```

Comment: You may want to check the return value from `AttachConsole` and use a MessageBox instead if it fails, just in case the process wasn't started from a console.

Comment: How exactly is your proposed solution *"an MFC application"*, as requested in the question?

Answer (score 0):

This is useful:

[How do I get the application exit code from a Windows command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334879/how-do-i-get-the-application-exit-code-from-a-windows-command-line)

```
Start /wait program.exe
Echo %errorlevel%
```

So, bring up prompt, run app, app sets an error number in InitInstance and closes, then you display error number.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `cout` to display data on the console, e.g .:

```
std::cout<< "Hello World"
```